# Unity dimensions when publishing for multiple platforms

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I plan to publish my unity game (a simple 2d game) on Android, Web and ios.

So, when I finish my project after testing in the web player, what do I have to consider
when publishing to all the platforms?

If my game is dimensions 900 px hight and 400 px width, will it fit in all screens when I publish 
it for iOS and android.

Do I need to change some things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this post might be of use to you: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/660799/scale-camera-to-fit-screen-size.html

Overall, it really depends on how far you go. The easiest route to go would be letter-boxing. Keeping your game area the same size and then fitting the camera to the aspect ratio at start-up.

Obviously, this is a pretty common issue people come upon when porting their games, so there are tools made. I've never used it, but [AspectRatioEnforcer](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=AspectRatioEnforcer) looks like a pretty simple tool that will ensure your game is playable on any platform.

After implementing something, its always good to test it in the Unity editor, switching resolutions around and seeing what happens.